# Symfony 6 Type error in Form for getting id from another class

Tags: forms, symfony, entities

I have the following error

My two classes :

```
<?php

//Entity/Cars.php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CarsRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;


#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CarsRepository::class)]
#[Vich\Uploadable]
class Cars
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $Brand = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $Model = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $Year = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $Kilometers = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $Description = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $TypeFuel = null;

    #[Vich\UploadableField(mapping: "cars", fileNameProperty: "image", mimeType: "image/jpeg")]
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'cars', targetEntity: Images::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
    private ?Images $Image = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->Image = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getBrand(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Brand;
    }

    public function setBrand(string $Brand): static
    {
        $this->Brand = $Brand;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getModel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Model;
    }

    public function setModel(string $Model): static
    {
        $this->Model = $Model;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getYear(): ?int
    {
        return $this->Year;
    }

    public function setYear(int $Year): static
    {
        $this->Year = $Year;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getKilometers(): ?int
    {
        return $this->Kilometers;
    }

    public function setKilometers(int $Kilometers): static
    {
        $this->Kilometers = $Kilometers;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $Description): static
    {
        $this->Description = $Description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTypeFuel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->TypeFuel;
    }

    public function setTypeFuel(string $TypeFuel): static
    {
        $this->TypeFuel = $TypeFuel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Images>
     */
    public function getImage(): ?Images
    {
        return $this->Image;
    }

    public function addImage(Images $image): self
    {
        /*if (!$this->Image->getCars($image)) {
            $this->Image->addImage($image);
            $image->setCars($this);
        }*/
        $this->Images = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeImage(Images $image): static
    {
        if ($this->Image->removeElement($image)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($image->getCars() === $this) {
                $image->setCars(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
<?php

//Entity/Images.php
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ImagesRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

#[UniqueEntity('Name')]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ImagesRepository::class)]
#[Vich\Uploadable]
class Images
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $Name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $Path = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'Image')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Cars $cars = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Name;
    }

    public function setName(string $Name): static
    {
        $this->Name = $Name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPath(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Path;
    }

    public function setPath(string $Path): static
    {
        $this->Path = $Path;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCars(): ?Cars
    {
        return $this->cars;
    }

    public function setCars(?Cars $cars): self
    {
        // unset the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($cars === null && $this->cars !== null) {
            $this->cars->addImage(null);
        }

        // set the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($cars !== null && $cars->getImage() !== $this) {
            $cars->addImage($this);
        }

        $this->cars = $cars;
        //$this->cars = $cars;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My form

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Cars;
use App\Entity\Images;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver\BackedEnumValueResolver;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;


class CarsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $group = new Cars();
        $builder
            ->add('Brand')
            ->add('Model')
            ->add('Year')
            ->add('Kilometers')
            ->add('Description')
            ->add('TypeFuel')
            ->add('Image',EntityType::class,[
                'class'=>  Images::class,
                'choices'=>$group->getId(),
            ])
            /*->add('Image', VichImageType::class, [
                'delete_label' => 'Remove file',
            ]*/
            //->add("Image", CollectionType::class)
            /*->add('Image', VichFileType::class, [
                'entry_type' => CollectionType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'download_uri' => true,
                    // Ajoutez d'autres options selon vos besoins
                ],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'label' => 'Images', // Étiquette pour le champ de collection
            ])*/;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Cars::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

How to type this to have a dialog box and make a relation to the picture in Class Entity ? Trying to find solution for this 'generic' problem and cannot find the right one. Trying to adapt the solution of doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Trying to find solution in google search...
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: Modified my Image field in form ->add('Image',EntityType::class,[
                'class'=>  Images::class,
                'choice_label' => 'Name',

            ]) Now getting App\Entity\Cars::getImage(): Return value must be of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection, null returned after submiting form it's same for ->add('Image',EntityType::class,[
                'class'=>  Images::class,
                'choice_label' => 'ID',

            ])

Comment: You should initialize your collections in a `__construct` method like in Images::class: `public function __construct(){ $this->Cars = new ArrayCollection(); }`